# How do I get a stack trace in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, stack-trace

The Objective Caml language will only produce stack traces if you ask for them just right - what are the requirements for both bytecode and native code?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Compile with -g and set environment variable OCAMLRUNPARAM=b

Comment: For native code, I believe this only works for OCaml v3.10 or later.

Answer (score 11):

Some [Printexc](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printexc.html) functions let you do this programmatically.

Comment: Specifically `Printexc.record_backtrace true`.

Answer (score 5):

Because it looks like you can only get traces for exceptions on unix you can fork and throw the exception in the second process. This way the main process can continue:

```
export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b
# compile with -g

flush_all(); let r = Unix.fork() in if r == 0 then raise Exit
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ocamlbuild instead of invoking compiler directly, you can use the `debug` tag. From the [manual](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc#tags-and-the-code-_tags-code-file):

> With OCamlbuild, you can simply add the debug tag to your program’s targets, and it will sort out when to insert the -g flag or not.

For example, if you are building a file `foo.ml` with package `bar` then your `_tags` file will have a line:

```
<foo.ml>: package(bar), debug
```

This will insert the appropriate `-g` flags while building bytecode/native files. However, you still need to set the environment variable using `export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b` as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, you need to compile your project with debugging info and run it with the `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b` environment variable.

A convenient way to have Ocamlbuild compile an entire project with debugging info but without editing the `_tags` file is to specify a special debug target. From the [manual](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.02/htmlman/ocamlbuild.html#sec404):

> The preferred way of compiling code suitable for debugging with `ocamldebug` or profiling native code with `ocamlprof` is to use the appropriate target extensions, `.d.byte` for debugging or `.p.native`.

I use this technique for quick compile-run cycles on the command line. For example, to run `foo.ml`:

```sh
export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b

ocamlbuild -no-links foo.d.byte && _build/foo.d.byte
```